# Error while getting the list of remote images: Can't connect to GNS3 VM (GNS3 VM)

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I recently installed GNS3 and configured the GNS3 VM pretty well and life was good. After adding a ubuntu VM and making a few changes in the network adapter, I can't connect to the GNS3 VM any more. Someone help me on how to manually connect GNS3 VM into GNS3. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the right way. But I typically switch between projects to reconnect to GNS3 VM.